# Is it okay for all users to use one Twitter API Bearer Token?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Bearer Tokens don't need to be obtained from each user if you're just retrieving tweets with the Twitter API, right?

App users will not be able to fav or retweet from Tweets.

Is it a security risk to use one token for all users in this case?

Comment: There's no security risk to users, but your app itself will be limited to the number of calls it can make based on a single bearer token in use; and if that token is used by anyone else to masquerade as your app, then it will still contribute to your limits.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So it means there are no way to get tweets without user tokens for general apps, right? Twitter doesn't allow to scrape.

Comment: You can use a bearer token if you do not need the user to be authenticated but the rate limits will be shared for all users. Otherwise, you should use a user token. That's how the Twitter API works. You should not be trying to get data without using the API, correct.